# keeping track of own objects on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, object, canvas, tkinter

Up until now, whenever I've needed to work with multiple shapes on a tkinter canvas, they were just that - shapes. I get their tags with `canvas.find_all()` and manipulate their geometry by moving, resizing etc.
But I bumped into this problem which I can't seem to solve like this.
If I define a my own class and draw this object to the canvas, how can I keep track of all the objects on the canvas, in order to call their methods?

Say I define a `Bubble` class, which draws a bubbly thing to the screen. After every second I want it to change all the bubbles' colour to another colour, using their `change_colour` methods.

```
my_list = []
for n in range(10):
    bubble = Bubble()
    my_list.append(bubble)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    for item in my_list:
        item.change_colour()
```

I could append it to a big 'ol list, then iterate through it like I am doing here, but for cases with more objects this is far too slow!
What is the proper way of doing this?
As usual, thanks for any help!

As pointed out, `time.sleep()` doesn't make any sense, but it is not the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Very generally speaking, it's a bad idea to have either infinite loops or `sleep` commands in your Tkinter program. The window won't update, and user commands won't be registered, until your function ends and control returns to the mainloop. If you want something to happen periodically, use `root.after` or `root.after_idle`. Try that and see whether your `for item in my_list` approach really is the problem.

Comment: Alternatively, if the code you're sharing here isn't actually the code you're running, it's just the code you were thinking of writing before you decided it would be too inefficient: premature optimization is the root of all evil. You can't be sure how fast code really is unless you write it and run it and measure it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this is not actual code I'm using. I was using it to demonstrate my question as clearly as possible, but it isn't really relevant to the question. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The code I am working on is a star simulator, where I have up to 1000 items on the canvas, and lists become impractical. However, I imagine this should still be manageable somehow, as they are many basic operations

Comment: why is a list with 1000 items impractical? Keeping a list is definitely the simplest solution, and 1000 items is well within the bounds of something python can handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to give each item you create at least two tags. One tag would be "bubble" so that you can reference all bubbles at once, and the second would be a tag unique to each bubble.

For example:

```
class Bubble():
    def __init__(...):
        self.tag = "b-%d" % id(self)
        ...
        canvas.create_oval(..., tags=("bubble", self.tag))
        ...
```

With that, you can implement a `change_color` method on the `Bubble` class like the following, which will change all canvas items created by this instance of the class:

```
def change_color(self, color):
    canvas.itemconfigure(self.tag, fill=color)
```

You can then create a red bubble like this:

```
bubble = Bubble()
bubble.change_color("red")
```

This also lets you change all bubbles at once using the "bubble" tag:

```
canvas.itemconfigure("bubble", outline="blue")
```

If you want the bubbles to blink, you should *not* create a `while` loop. Instead, take advantage of the loop that is already running.

Do this by creating a function that does whatever you want, and then have that function schedule itself to run again via `after`. For example:

```
def blink(color="red"):
    canvas.itemconfigure("bubble", fill=color)
    new_color = "red" if color == "white" else "white"
    canvas.after(1000, blink, new_color)
```

This will cause all bubbles to blink every second as long as the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform custom individual changes to each item (say, changing each item's color to a brand new random color), then you can't do any better than iterating through each one and calling `itemconfig` on them individually.

However, if you want to make the same change to each item, you can tag your items and call `itemconfig` a single time, using that tag as your specifier.

Example:

```
import Tkinter
import random

root = Tkinter.Tk()
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

for i in range(1000):
    x = random.randint(0, 400)
    y = random.randint(0, 400)
    canvas.create_oval((x-5,y-5,x+5,y+5), fill="white", tags=("bubble"))

current_color = "white"
def change_colors():
    global current_color
    current_color = "white" if current_color == "black" else "black"
    canvas.itemconfig("bubble", fill = current_color)
    root.after(1000, change_colors)

root.after(1000, change_colors)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

However, as I indicated in an earlier comment, I'm still of the opinion that this is a premature optimization. Even if you have a thousand items, iterating through them and configuring them individually isn't noticeably slower than doing it with tags. Example:

```
import Tkinter
import random

root = Tkinter.Tk()
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

items = []
for i in range(1000):
    x = random.randint(0, 400)
    y = random.randint(0, 400)
    id = canvas.create_oval((x-5,y-5,x+5,y+5), fill="white")
    items.append(id)

current_color = "white"
def change_colors():
    global current_color
    current_color = "white" if current_color == "black" else "black"
    for id in items:
        canvas.itemconfig(id, fill = current_color)
    root.after(1000, change_colors)

root.after(1000, change_colors)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kevin, but perhaps my question was unclear. I am trying to call methods on my own objects on the canvas. I could just as well have used another method in the example, which, say, splits my bubble into two smaller bubbles

Answer (score 1):

The `Canvas.find_withtag()` method will return a list of the IDs of the all the matching objects specified by first argument. You can use that in conjunction with a dictionary to map those back to the corresponding instances of your class. Once you have that, you can call any of its methods.

```
import Tkinter
import random

BUBBLE_TAG = 'Bubble'
current_color = 'white'

class Bubble(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, size, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval((x-5,y-5,x+5,y+5), fill=color, 
                                     tags=BUBBLE_TAG)

    def change_color(self, new_color):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.id, fill=new_color)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

mapping = {}
for i in range(1000):
    x, y = random.randint(0, 400), random.randint(0, 400)
    color = 'black' if random.randint(0, 1) else 'white'
    obj = Bubble(canvas, x, y, 5, color)
    mapping[obj.id] = obj

def change_colors():
    for id in canvas.find_withtag(BUBBLE_TAG):
        current_color = canvas.itemcget(id, 'fill')
        new_color = 'black' if current_color == 'white' else 'white'
        mapping[id].change_color(new_color)  # calls method of object
    root.after(1000, change_colors)

root.after(1000, change_colors)
root.mainloop()
```

Here's an example of it running:

[image: sample of it running]